# Cannot reinitialise DataTable when I reload datatables after perform edit page return to list page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

On the list page user can edit info by click on Edit button and open details page for edit data.
After edit done return list page. This my source code

My JS listUser.js is embbed in jsp file at the bottom listusers.jsp

```html
<div class="c-body">
  <main class="c-main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="fade-in" id="content">
        <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">List Users</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-right">
            <button id="create_user" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tạo mới</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <table id="userTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered datatable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>Site</th>
    <th>Roles</th>
    <th>Areas</th>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
        </div>
        <script src="${contextPath}/user/listUser.js"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

listUser.js

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var userTable = $('#userTable').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/user/paginated",
            "data": function ( data ) {
         }},
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "username", "name" : "Username", "title" : "Username", "defaultContent" : ""},
                    { "data": "full_name", "name" : "Full Name" , "title" : "Full Name", "defaultContent" : ""},
                    { "data": "site_code", "name" : "Site" , "title" : "Site", "defaultContent" : ""},
                    { "data": "user_roles", "name" : "Roles", "title" : "Roles", "defaultContent" : ""},
                    { "data": "user_areas", "name" : "Areas", "title" : "Areas", "defaultContent" : ""},
                    { "data": "team_code", "name" : "Team", "title" : "Team", "defaultContent" : ""},
                    { "data": "status", "name" : "Status", "title" : "Status", "defaultContent" : ""},
                    { "targets": "no-sort", "orderable": false, "data": "null", "name" : "Thao tác", "title" : "Thao tác", "defaultContent" : "<button id='updateUser' name='updateUser' class='btn btn-primary btn-edit' type='button' aria-pressed='true'>Sửa</button>"}
                ]
    });

    $('#userTable').on('click', '.btn-edit', function(){
       var data = userTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
       //alert(data.user_id);
       let url = "user/updateUser?id=" + data.user_id;
       $("#content").load(url);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#update_user', function(){
            updateUser();
    });

    function updateUser() {
        ...

        var data = {
            ...
        };

        var json = JSON.stringify(data);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
              if(myObj.status == "1"){
                  $("#content").load("user/list");
              }
            }
         };
        xhr.open("POST", "/user/update");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xhr.send(json);
    }
});
```

The problem I occurred **DataTables warning: table id=userTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.**

Thanks you.

Comment: You have a comment `         //process data before sent to server.`. Is that what you really have in your code?

Comment: No. This is comment. No code process in here

Comment: Could you solve your problem? Is there more info to improve the answer?

Answer (score 1):

From [DataTable Docs](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3) (first result in search engine with the warning message you provided):

> DataTables has a wide range of configuration options which can be used to customise the table at initialisation time, but only at initialisation time. After a DataTable has been initialised any attempt to use these options will result in an error.

> Simply put, DataTables does not allow initialisation options to be altered at any time other than at initialisation time. Any manipulation of the table after initialisation must be done through the [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api) [...]

You are not showing how you initialize DataTable, so I can't help you further, unless you update your answer with more information.

#### Edit

After gathering more info from you, I now can understand what you are trying to do.

Essentially: DataTables expects it's DOM elements to be managed by itself. Once you initialize a DataTable, you should not manipulate any DOM related to it. If you want to show something like the user editing page and go back to the table after save, you need to choose one of the next 2 options:

- Completely unmount the DataTable before showing the user edit page and re-initialize it after saving user data and gathering new DataTable data from server.
- Don't detach DataTable DOM: show user form in a modal, or hide the DataTable instead of removing it, and unhide it again after user data has been saved. Updated data will need to be reinjected into a living DataTables, which I think will need the use of the `.ajax.data` initialization option.

Depends on how much data is being transferred and processed I'd choose one or the other.

Comment: I have updated more information about initialize DataTable.

Comment: I think I need a little context about your HTML structure. What are the used elements `#userTable`, `#content` and `#update_user`?

Comment: I still don't see the element with ID `content`.

Comment: The ID content in master page.
<div class="c-body">
        <main class="c-main">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="fade-in" id="content">

            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
The Master page contain load ajax pages (list page, details for edit page)

Comment: As I can understand, you are trying to replace the whole table with the results from server at `user/updateUser?id=${data.uder_id}` (which is HTML data) after user update. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, On list page. I click edit button in row of table. Page details show for me edit data. After perform done return to list page. thanks

Comment: I tried option 1 but It still not work.
$('#userTable').on('click', '.btn-edit', function(){
       var data = userTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
       let url = "user/updateUser?id=" + data.user_id;
       userTable.destroy();
       $("#content").load(url);
    });

Comment: I detroyed datatable before load edit page when user click edit button but not ok. still occurred the problem.

Comment: Is the error coming from the same line as before? Did you re-initialized the DataTable before re-using its api after update? Please, share an example of what is gathered from `updateUser` XHR call. Also, as you are recreating all the DOM, you'll need to unlisten and re-listen click event on `#userTable .btn-edit`.

Comment: when the first edit infor return to list page I see it ok. But 2nd the problems will appear.
action update call 2 times and list and listUser.js the same
You can see image I attached https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESRhV.png

Comment: You have not answered any of my questions... Do you prefer to chat?